# WordProblem on factors and remainder theorem

Tags: divisibility, factoring

Mr.Chaalu while travelling by Ferry queen has travelled the distance one Kilometer more, than the fare he paid per km. Initially he had total amount of Rs.350/- in his wallet. Now he is only left with the minimum sum of (if all the distance travelled by him is in integers)?

Options
1. Rs.26/-
2. Rs.8/-
3. Rs.29/-
4. Can't be determined.

Answer: Rs.8/-359

**Need help on how to approach this problem**

My Approach:
Lets say distance travelled by Chaalu is x.
Total distance covered by him is (x+1)

Lets say fare to pay per km is y

So (x+1)*y < 350

So we have to find pair of factors starting from 349/- **but not sure upto which number**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Fare/km is N, and the distance traveled is N+1, and the total fare is N*(N+1). When N is 18, the total fare is Rs.342. The remainder is Rs.8.

Comment: From Fare per km(which is N in your case), you are calculating the distance travelled as (N+1), I'm not getting this part! Suppose say Fare/Km is $5, how come distance travelled will be $(5+1)?

Comment: It's in the first sentence. The problem is, the person who wrote the word problem was think numerically, and not considering units. Thus, without units, the price per km could be N and without units, the distance would be N+1. When you add units, what we did makes sense. And you get the answer you stated was correct. The difficulty was in deciphering the text. So remember, they wanted the MINIMUM remainder. Thus, N must be 18 for N*(N+1) to be the minimum below 350.